# Unable to delete .lock files within geodatabase using Python

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, lock

I am having problems with lock files while deleting and copying geodatabases for backup purposes.

```
print "Now backing up your Geodatabase"
distutils.dir_util.remove_tree (r"\\Msukserver\gis\geodatabase BACKUP\EVERYONE\Mining Features (MATTHEW).gdb", 0, 0) # deletes 'everyone' backup copy
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(r"\\Msukserver\gis\geodatabase BACKUP\MATT\Mining Features (MATTHEW).gdb", r"\\Msukserver\gis\geodatabase BACKUP\EVERYONE\Mining Features (MATTHEW).gdb") # backup the last backup to 'everyone'
print "old backup copied"
distutils.dir_util.remove_tree(r"\\Msukserver\gis\geodatabase BACKUP\MATT\Mining Features (MATTHEW).gdb", 0, 0) # deletes last backup
print "old backup deleted"
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(r"C:\GIS Home\Mining Features (MATTHEW).gdb", r"\\Msukserver\gis\geodatabase BACKUP\MATT\Mining Features (MATTHEW).gdb") # copy mining features to create new backup
print "::::::::::::::::::::::Backup Complete::::::::::::::::::::::"
raw_input("Push Return key to close...")
```

I am getting a 'permission denied' error on the '.lock' files. Is there a way of copying/deleting all the file except those with a .lock extension? or a way to continue/force with errors? I am aware that I am currently copying/deleting the entire directory and may need to change my code to copy/delete files only.

Comment: Have you considered using [`arcpy.Copy_management`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/0017/001700000051000000.htm) and [`arcpy.Delete_management`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000051000000)to do this?

Comment: Also if you have the geodatabase open in ArcMap, ArcCatalog, etc., you will not be able to delete it except within the application that has the lock on it.

Comment: For the record, this is probably a good thing. `.lock` files generally indicate that something is *in use*. You don't want to delete something in use by an application. You want to stop using it first. (I consider it a weakness of the GDB format that you could go delete other files that belong to it while this one is locked.) Also, don't use `distutils` for file management; that's for creating distribution packages for Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using arcpy to back up your geodatabases. Example:

```
workspace = r"workspace\file\path"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
print "Set Workspace"
backup_location = r"new\folder\path" + "\\" + "workspace.gdb"
print "Backing up workspace"
arcpy.Copy_management(workspace, backup_location)
print "Clearing Workspace cache"
arcpy.env.workspace = ""
arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management(workspace)
print "Deleting original copy"
arcpy.Delete_management(workspace)
print "Finished backing up"
```

Any time you use python to access/manipulate a geodatabase you create a lock on that geodatabase. By using arcpy you can copy, clear the lock, and delete to ensure it's all done properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try omitting the ".lock" extension in order to avoid removing those files. However, I think you may have to use the cleanup function through ArcObjects to remove everything.

```
folder = "folder path"
for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
    if ".lock" not in the_file:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            else:
                shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception, e:
            arcpy.AddMessage(e)
```

Comment: The fact you can't delete the `.lock` file means something is using the file. You shouldn't go trying to delete all the files in the GDB while something is using it.